# Consume ASMX webservice in PhoneGap

Tags: web-services, cordova, asmx

How Can we use **ASMX** web service in Phonegap ? Is connsuming **ASMX** web service support all mobile OS like Android,Windows Phone and iOS ?

Comment: I know for sure for Android,Windows Phone. I believe that iOS support them.

Comment: Thank sir. can you give me some working example for understand better way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    url: Your_webservice_url,
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        ModifiedSince: modifiedSince
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("The server returned " + data.length);
        //Play with the received json data.
    },
    error: function(model, response) {
        alert("Web service error: " + response.responseText);
    }
});
```